# Must not versus cannot

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, american-english

It is stated in my grammar textbook that in American English people use “***must not***” when they want to say that something is improbable or it is improbable that somebody has done something:

American English:

> *It **must not** be broken, because I checked it before delivery.*

British English:

> *It **cannot** be broken, because I checked it before delivery.*

Later in the textbook, it is stated that we use “***must not***” to order someone that it is necessary that they do not do something:

> *This machine is very dangerous, you **must not** even touch it.*

Now, my question is: can’t we use “***can not***” instead of “***must not***” for the first case? Because I think it’s clearer and it is even more logical.

Answer (score 2):

The first examples are what is called the *epistemic* use of the modals "can" and "must": they're saying things about the speaker's knowledge and expectations, not about possibilities or powers in the real world. They both say "I am sure that" or "I conclude that" it isn't broken. Certainly *can't* is more likely there in BrE: I don't know about AmE.

In BrE, epistemic "mustn't" is more commonly used to mean something like "I conclude that", often with a hint of surprise, eg *he mustn't have found the box* means something like  "I thought he would find the box, but judging from what happened afterwards, he didn't find it". *It musn't be broken* is certainly possible, but has a hint of surprise which is not there in *It can't be broken*.

The other use is *deontic*: it's not about the speaker's knowledge, but about potentialities and obligations in the real world. In that context, "must" and "can" have very different meanings: *you must not even touch it* means "you are not permitted to touch it", or "you risk some awful consequence if you touch it", whereas "*you cannot even touch it* (note that "cannot" is one word, not two) means "it is not possible for you to touch it". This can sometimes be intepreted as social or institutional possibility, and so means the same as "must not", but it could also refer to some other kind or possibility, such as "it is not physically possible for you to touch it".

The relationship between epistemic *can* and *must* has little in common with the relationship between deontic *can* and *must*.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I'm afraid you didn't answer my question which is the American English usage of "can not" for the first case or as you say "epistemic".

Comment: Oh, I see. Then I can't answer, then, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

*Can* refers to ability.  If you *can* do something, you're able to do it--it doesn't mean you will do it, or have to do it, but you are *able* to do it.

*Must* means not having a choice to do something.  If you *must* do X, you don't have a choice not do X.

Keep in mind modals in English are often "misused" for politeness and authority-deference purposes.  For example, instead of directly asking *Help me with this* you might say *Can you help me with this* to sound more polite.